# How to create a custum sort function for ng-grid angularjs

Tags: angularjs

the default sort of ng-grid is not alphanumeric.
is it possible to apply a custom sort function in order to obtain a correct sort, as :

'11' '2' 'eé' 'ed' => '2' '11' 'ed' 'eé'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define [your own sorting function](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/wiki/Sorting-and-filtering).

Here's an [**example with your data**](http://plnkr.co/edit/nvCGLqnKAWVyPkGIcHCm?p=preview). (Fixed it using [Devin Torres' Natural Sorting algorithm](http://devintorr.es/blog/2010/06/25/a-natural-sorting-comparator-for-javascripts-arrayprototypesort/))

```
var myAwesomeSortFn = function(a,b){

  var NUMBER_GROUPS = /(-?\d*\.?\d+)/g;

  var myAwesomeSortFn = function(a, b) {

    var aa = String(a).split(NUMBER_GROUPS),
    bb = String(b).split(NUMBER_GROUPS),
    min = Math.min(aa.length, bb.length);

    for (var i = 0; i < min; i++) {
      var x = parseFloat(aa[i]) || aa[i].toLowerCase(),
      y = parseFloat(bb[i]) || bb[i].toLowerCase();
      if (x < y) return -1;
      else if (x > y) return 1;
    }

  return 0;
};

$scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: 11},
                 {name: "Tiancum", age: 2},
                 {name: "Jacob", age: 'eé'},
                 {name: "Nephi", age: 'ed'}];  
$scope.gridOptions = { 
    data: 'myData',
    columnDefs: [{field: 'name', displayName: 'Name'}, {field:'age', displayName:'Age', sortFn: myAwesomeSortFn}]
};
```

Comment: It looks like in my version of UI Grid, the property is called `sortingAlgorithm` instead of `sortFn`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have so far:

```js
        $scope.links = {
            sortFun: function(a, b) { console.log('a:' + a + ', b: ' + b); }
        };

...


$scope.data.grid.columnDefs.push(
  {'field': key, 'sortingAlgorithm': $scope.links.sortFun }
);   

...
```

```
                $scope.data.grid.columnDefs.push({'field': key, 'sortingAlgorithm': $scope.links.sortFun });
```